# Exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module. Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, memory, dllimport, access-violation, protected

## I have created a c++ dll and using in the Project using [DllImport("dll")] while i am using this dll after build it crashes at following function AES_init_ctx();

This is my DLL Code:

"DLLCreation.h"

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void AES_init_ctx(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void AES_ECB_encrypt(const struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf);
```

"DLLCreation.cpp"

// DLLCreation.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL.
//

```
DLLCREATION_API void AES_init_ctx(struct AES_ctx* ctx, const uint8_t* key)
{
    KeyExpansion(ctx->RoundKey, key);
}


DLLCREATION_API void AES_ECB_encrypt(const struct AES_ctx* ctx, uint8_t* buf)
{
    // The next function call encrypts the PlainText with the Key using AES algorithm.
    Cipher((state_t*)buf, ctx->RoundKey);
}
```

"Program.cs"

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct AES_ctx
    {
       public byte[] RoundKey;
        public byte[] Iv;

    };

    private const string dllPath = "C:\\Users\\RnD User\\source\\repos\\RizwanCodeDLL\\x64\\Debug\\DLLCreation.dll";
    [DllImport(dllPath,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    //static extern void AES256(byte[] plain,byte[] key,byte[] cipher);
    static extern void AES_init_ctx(AES_ctx ctx, byte[] key);
    [DllImport(dllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern void AES_ECB_encrypt(AES_ctx ctx, byte[] buf);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        byte[] IV = { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff }; //plaintext example
        byte[] key = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f}; 
        byte[] cipher = { };
       

        byte[] b = Program.MarshalUnsignedCharArray(IV,key);
        // Console.WriteLine(b);
    }

    public static byte[] MarshalUnsignedCharArray(byte[] IV, byte[] key)
    {
        AES_ctx ctx = new AES_ctx();
        ctx.RoundKey = new byte[240];
        ctx.Iv = new byte[16];
        AES_init_ctx(ctx, key);
        AES_ECB_encrypt(ctx,IV);
        return IV;
    }

}
```

i have tried above mention process.i have made public arrays.I am getting error which is my title.

Comment: The arrays need [MarshalAs(ByValArray, SizeConst=...)]

Comment: @HansPassant is it work for .so file?